# Blazor Dynamic Fields and ASP.Net.Core with Validation/Validators

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor, blazor, blazor-server-side

I trying to write a Blazor app (server-side to start) that dynamically creates its form fields with validation. I love the validation/validators that come with Razor that bind to models, but I can't figure out how to do it for dynamically created fields (aka, no model).

This is what I have.  I would totally appreciate some guidance.
Thanks! Jason

Startup.cs

```
...
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddRazorPages();
            services.AddServerSideBlazor();

            services.AddSingleton<DynamicControlService>();
        }
...
```

ControlTypes.cs

```
namespace DynamicContent
{
    public enum ControlTypes
    {
        Text                = 1,
        Date                = 2,
        DateTime            = 3,
        Time                = 4, 
        SingleSelect        = 5, // DropdownList
        MultiSelect         = 6,
        Boolean             = 7, // Checkbox or Slide
        Email               = 8,
        RadioButtonList     = 9
    }
}
```

ControlDetails.cs

```
namespace DynamicContent
{
    public class ControlDetails
    {
        public string ID { get; set; }
        public string FieldName { get; set; }
        public ControlTypes Type { get; set; } = ControlTypes.Text;
        public string Label { get; set; }
        public bool IsRequired { get; set; }
        public bool IsReadOnly { get; set; } = false;
        public string Tooltip { get; set; } // ToDo: Default to Label (if not set)
        public string Placeholder { get; set; }
        public string Min { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        public string Max { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    }
}
```

DynamicControlService.cs

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace DynamicContent
{
    public class DynamicControlService
    {
        public List<ControlDetails> GetControls()
        {
// Eventually this will pull from a database 
            var result = new List<ControlDetails>();

            result.Add(new ControlDetails { FieldName = "firstName", Label = "First Name", IsRequired = true });
            result.Add(new ControlDetails { FieldName = "lastName", Label = "Last Name", IsRequired = true });
            result.Add(new ControlDetails { FieldName = "birthDate", Type = ControlTypes.Date, Label = "Birth Date",
                IsRequired = false, Tooltip = "Please enter Birth Date in mm/dd/yyyy format" });

            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

Counter.razor

```
@page "/counter"
@inject DynamicControlService _controlService

<form>
    @foreach (var control in ControlList)
    {
        <div class="form-group">

            <!-- Label -->
            <label asp-for=@(control.FieldName) class="label-control">
                @(control.Label) @if (control.IsRequired)
                {<b> *</b>}
            </label>

            <!-- Input field -->
            @switch (control.Type)
            {
                case ControlTypes.Text:
                    <input type="text" id="@control.ID" class="form-control" asp-for=@(control.FieldName)
                            @bind-value="@Values[control.Label]" required="@control.IsRequired" />
                    break;

                case ControlTypes.Email:
                    <input type="email" id="@control.ID" class="form-control" value="@Values[control.Label]"
                            required="@control.IsRequired" />
                    break;

                case ControlTypes.Date:
                    <input type="date" id="@control.ID" class="form-control" value="@Values[control.Label]"
                            required="@control.IsRequired" @onchange="@(a => ValueChanged(a, control.Label))"
                            min="1900-01-01" max="2999-12-31"/>
                    break;
            }


            <!-- Validation Message -->
            <span asp-validation-for=@(control.FieldName) class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>

        <!-- @@((MarkupString)buildInputField(control)) -->
    }

    <p />
    <button @onclick="OnClick" type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>

@code
{
    private List<ControlDetails> ControlList;
    private Dictionary<string, string> Values;

    // ToDo: protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        base.OnInitialized();

        ControlList = _controlService.GetControls();
        Values = ControlList.ToDictionary(c => c.Label, c => "");
    }

    void ValueChanged(ChangeEventArgs a, string label)
    {
        // ToDo: force date to be within min/max (e.g. typing 9999 is not valid given max of 2999) 
        Values[label] = a.Value.ToString();
    }

    string GetValue(string label)
    {
        return Values[label];
    }

    private void OnClick(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        // send your Values
    }

    // ToDo: Build a method for creating a field with label support 
    private string buildInputField(ControlDetails control)
    {
        return "";
        /*
        string inputField = $"<input type=\"{control.Type}\" id=\"@control.ID\" " +
                "class=\"form-control\" asp-for=@(control.FieldName) " +
                "@bind-value=\"@Values[control.Label]\" required=\"@control.IsRequired";

        inputField += "/>";

        return inputField;
        */
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Jason, I am building something similar and I am facing the same problem, have you got a workaround? thanks

Comment: me too... have you figured it out ?

Comment: It doesn't seem possible - I've spent hours finding some information on this!

Comment: Yeah, I honestly hit a frustration point, and decided I would just come back later.  Sigh, I haven't spent any more time on this in a while.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old, but I just recently got this working albeit I had to use a thin wrapper model class to contain the models representing the edit fields. I couldn't figure out a way to get it to work without doing so unfortunately.

My example is for a Blazor Web-assembly app using Syncfusion components and I used the Blazored.FluentValidation library instead of Data Annotations (https://github.com/Blazored/FluentValidation). Here's the relevant code.

Here how I'm generating the edit control markup. My example has the concept of field groups for the purposes of organizing edit controls on the UI which is not essential, but I wanted to show how the fluent validation can cascade down an object graph. The ValueExpression is essential for getting the validation to style the UI components properly. I'm using a combination of Value and ValueChanged for getting and setting values to and from the model.

```
    public RenderFragment CreateEditComponents(List<CustomFieldGroupInfoDTO> groupsList) => builder =>
{
    int seq = 0;  // sequence number for builder

    // Open Bootstrap row div
    builder.OpenElement(seq++, "div");
    builder.AddAttribute(seq++, "class", "row");

    foreach (CustomFieldGroupInfoDTO fieldGroup in groupsList.OrderBy(g => g.DisplayOrder))
    {
        // Open Bootstrap column div
        builder.OpenElement(seq++, "div");
        builder.AddAttribute(seq++, "class", "col-md-6 mb-3");

        // Add group header
        if (fieldGroup.DisplayGroupName)
        {
            builder.OpenElement(seq++, "h3");
            builder.AddContent(seq++, fieldGroup.GroupName);
            builder.CloseElement();  // Close h3
        }

        foreach (CustomFieldEditorInfoDTO fieldInfo in fieldGroup.CustomFields.OrderBy(f => f.DisplayOrder))
        {
            if ((CustomFieldType)fieldInfo.CustomFieldTypeID == PantryManager.Shared.Enums.CustomFieldType.TextBox)
            {
                builder.OpenComponent(seq++, typeof(Syncfusion.Blazor.Inputs.SfTextBox));                    
                builder.AddAttribute(seq++, "Value", fieldInfo.StringValue);
                builder.AddAttribute(seq++, "PlaceHolder", fieldInfo.FieldName);
                builder.AddAttribute(seq++, "FloatLabelType", FloatLabelType.Always);
                builder.AddAttribute(seq++, "ValueChanged", EventCallback.Factory.Create<string?>(this, value => fieldInfo.StringValue = value));
                builder.AddAttribute(seq++, "ValueExpression", (Expression<Func<string?>>)(() => fieldInfo.StringValue));
                builder.CloseComponent();                  

                builder.OpenComponent(seq++, typeof(ValidationMessage<string?>));
                builder.AddAttribute(seq++, "For", (Expression<Func<string?>>)(() => fieldInfo.StringValue));
                builder.CloseComponent();
            }
            else if ((CustomFieldType)fieldInfo.CustomFieldTypeID == PantryManager.Shared.Enums.CustomFieldType.DropDownList)
            {
```

Here is the markup for the form itself. The Model is set to my overarching wrapper which contains field groups, which in turn contain editor field objects. The FluentValidationValidator component comes from the FluentValidation library and we grab a reference to it for use in the submit handler.

```
<EditForm Model="@editorContainer" OnValidSubmit="@Submit" OnInvalidSubmit="@InvalidSubmit">
    <FluentValidationValidator @ref="_fluentValidationValidator" Options="@(options => options.IncludeAllRuleSets())" />
    @* <ValidationSummary></ValidationSummary> *@
    @CreateEditComponents(@editorContainer.CustomFieldGroupInfoDTOs)    
    @if (canEdit)
    {
        <div class="col-12 mt-3">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
        </div>
    }
</EditForm>

@code {
    private FluentValidationValidator? _fluentValidationValidator;
 
    CustomFieldEditorInfoDTOContainer editorContainer = new CustomFieldEditorInfoDTOContainer();
```

In the submit form handler, call ValidateAsync() on the _fluentValidationValidator component.

```
        if (await _fluentValidationValidator!.ValidateAsync())
        {                    
            //handle post
        }                
        else
        {
            
        }
```

Here are my model classes that use the FluentValidation library. As mentioned earlier, the edit container set to the EditForm's model contains groups, which contain editor fields. Each one of these models implements the AbstractValidator class from the FluentValidation library. This allows them to set the validation rules for itself which includes complex types or collections of complex types that it may contain.

```
   public class CustomFieldGroupInfoDTO
   {
       public string GroupName { get; set; }
       public bool DisplayGroupName { get; set; }
       public int DisplayOrder { get; set; }

       public List<CustomFieldEditorInfoDTO> CustomFields { get; set; } = new List<CustomFieldEditorInfoDTO>();
   }

   public class CustomFieldEditorInfoDTOContainer
   {
       public List<CustomFieldGroupInfoDTO> CustomFieldGroupInfoDTOs { get; set; } = new List<CustomFieldGroupInfoDTO>();
   }

   public class CustomFieldEditorInfoDTO
   {
       public int ClientID { get; set; }
       public int? ClientCustomFieldDataID { get; set; }
       public int ClientCustomFieldID { get; set; }
       public int CustomFieldTypeID { get; set; }
       public string FieldName { get; set; }
       public List<CustomFieldInfoOptionDTO> FieldOptions { get; set; } = new List<CustomFieldInfoOptionDTO>();
       public List<int> SelectedOptionIds { get; set; } = new List<int>();
       //public object? Value { get; set; }
       public DateTime? DateTimeValue { get; set; }
       public int? IntValue { get; set; }
       public decimal? DecimalValue { get; set; }
       public string? StringValue { get; set; }
       public bool? BoolValue { get; set; }
       public int DisplayOrder { get; set; }
       public bool IsRequired { get; set; }
   }

   public class CustomFieldInfoOptionDTO
   {
       public int Value { get; set; }
       public string DisplayText { get; set; }
   }

   public class CustomFieldEditorInfoDTOContainerValidator : AbstractValidator<CustomFieldEditorInfoDTOContainer>
   {
       public CustomFieldEditorInfoDTOContainerValidator()
       {
           RuleSet("CustomFieldEditorRules", () =>
           {
               RuleForEach(p => p.CustomFieldGroupInfoDTOs).SetValidator(new CustomFieldGroupInfoDTOValidator());
           });
       }
   }

   public class CustomFieldGroupInfoDTOValidator : AbstractValidator<CustomFieldGroupInfoDTO>
   {
       public CustomFieldGroupInfoDTOValidator()
       {
           RuleSet("CustomFieldGroupEditorRules", () =>
           {
               RuleForEach(p => p.CustomFields).SetValidator(new CustomFieldEditorInfoDTOValidator());
           });
       }
   }

   public class CustomFieldEditorInfoDTOValidator : AbstractValidator<CustomFieldEditorInfoDTO>
   {
       public CustomFieldEditorInfoDTOValidator()
       {
           RuleSet("FieldValue", () =>
           {
               When(dto => dto.IsRequired, () =>
               {
                   RuleFor(dto => dto.SelectedOptionIds)
                       .Must(optionIds => optionIds != null && optionIds.Count > 0)
                       .When(dto => (CustomFieldType)dto.CustomFieldTypeID == CustomFieldType.DropDownList
                           || (CustomFieldType)dto.CustomFieldTypeID == CustomFieldType.MultiSelectDropDownList)
                       .WithMessage(dto => $"{dto.FieldName} is required");

                   RuleFor(dto => dto.DateTimeValue)
                       .NotNull()
                       .When(dto => (CustomFieldType)dto.CustomFieldTypeID == CustomFieldType.DatePicker)
                       .WithMessage(dto => $"{dto.FieldName} is required");

                   RuleFor(dto => dto.StringValue)
                       .NotEmpty()
                       .When(dto => (CustomFieldType)dto.CustomFieldTypeID == CustomFieldType.TextBox
                           || (CustomFieldType)dto.CustomFieldTypeID == CustomFieldType.TextArea
                           || (CustomFieldType)dto.CustomFieldTypeID == CustomFieldType.EmailTextBox
                           || (CustomFieldType)dto.CustomFieldTypeID == CustomFieldType.PhoneTextBox)
                       .WithMessage(dto => $"{dto.FieldName} is required");

                   RuleFor(dto => dto.IntValue)
                       .NotNull()
                       .When(dto => (CustomFieldType)dto.CustomFieldTypeID == CustomFieldType.IntegerTextBox)
                       .WithMessage(dto => $"{dto.FieldName} is required");

                   RuleFor(dto => dto.DecimalValue)
                       .NotNull()
                       .When(dto => (CustomFieldType)dto.CustomFieldTypeID == CustomFieldType.DecimalTextBox
                           || (CustomFieldType)dto.CustomFieldTypeID == CustomFieldType.CurrencyTextBox)
                       .WithMessage(dto => $"{dto.FieldName} is required");
               });

               // Phone number validation
               RuleFor(dto => dto.StringValue)
                   .Matches(@"^\(?([0-9]{3})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{3})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})$")
                   .When(dto => (CustomFieldType)dto.CustomFieldTypeID == CustomFieldType.PhoneTextBox && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(dto.StringValue))
                   .WithMessage(dto => $"{dto.FieldName} is not a valid phone number");

               // Email validation
               RuleFor(dto => dto.StringValue)
                   .EmailAddress()
                   .When(dto => (CustomFieldType)dto.CustomFieldTypeID == CustomFieldType.EmailTextBox && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(dto.StringValue))
                   .WithMessage(dto => $"{dto.FieldName} is not a valid email address");
           });
       }
   }
```

The above implementation will result in edit controls behaving just like the more basic implementations seen using DataAnnotations with statically marked-up edit fields. Hope this helps someone!

Comment: I will so have to give this another try.  Thank you for sharing!